# Delete all files except those that contain terms listed in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to remove all files from a directory that are not partially matched to a list in a text file.

I can't figure out the matching.  The underscore `_` can be used to delimite the match. `1` would match with `1_`, but not `11`.

```
$ cat /files/keep_list.txt  
1
22
333
4444
$ ls /files/    
1_a.gif         # don't delete
1_b.gif         # don't delete
1_.jpeg         # don't delete
2_c.gif         # delete
2_d.gif         # delete
2_.jpeg         # delete
22_.jpeg        # don't delete
23_.jpeg        # delete
333_abc.gif     # don't delete
4445_123.jpeg   # delete
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Can you rephrase it to make it more clear?
Also add what have you tried so far.

Comment: Would 123 match 4445_123.jpeg?

Comment: If the filenames contain no whitespace or control characters, you can do `rm $(ls - 1 | grep -v -f <(sed '/^[0-9]/s/$/_/' keep_files.txt) -)`. If the number of files exceed the number that can be processed in one command, you can process the list with  `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd fill `GLOBIGNORE` with globs that would match files to be kept and run `rm *_*` to get rid of everything else that has an underscore in its name.

```
#!/bin/bash -
mapfile -t parts <keep_list.txt

for part in "${parts[@]}"; do
  printf -v GLOBIGNORE '%s:%q_*:*_%q[_.]*' \
    "$GLOBIGNORE" "$part"{,}
done

echo rm *_*
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.

Comment: This works.  Thank you.  There is one issue.  I would like the script to ignore files that don't have the underscore.  This way I could leave the script in the directory along with the file list.  Also the lost+found is on the list to delete too.

Comment: @dyna Updated, check it out

Comment: Oh, ```*_*``` after ``` rm```.  Sorry that simple change did not occur to me.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bash solution, but in python (which should also be available on any linux system):

deleteButKeepSome.py:

```
import os

match = ['1', '22', '333', '4444'] # put the keep_list in here

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/files'):
    for file in files:
        if file[:file.find('_')] not in match:
            os.remove(f'{root}/{file}')
```

To run:

```
$ python deleteButKeepSome.py
```

Be careful to execute it in the correct folder!

Comment: This is a bash question, what language is this?

Comment: oh sorry. it's python script. I think it still can run in linux.